# I need to normalize my data in order to make a cluster in Rstudio

Tags: r

I need to make an assigment for school in R however, we had 0 training what so ever. I tried to watch videos but I just can't work it out.

I need to cluster data from this data set:

[image]

I've tried:

```
z <- AP2[,]
m <-apply(z,1,mean)
s <- apply(z,1,sd)
z <- scale(z,m,s)
```

and also:

```
z <- AP2[,]
AP2 <- matrix(sample(1:1000,102*4), ncol=102,nrow=4)
for(i in 1:nrow(AP2)){
  x <- AP2[i, ]
  AP2[i, ] <- scale(x, min(x), max(x)-min(x))
}
distance <- dist(x)
hc.c <- hclust(distance)
plot(hc.c)
```

But as I said, I have no experience I just tried to "copy" other peoples work.

Comment: Try `scale(AP2)`

Comment: In which part of the code? Cause these are two different codes I tried to run.

Comment: Right after you import the data frame into R.